# SQL Float not yielding consistent matching results against MS Access Double

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2003, floating-accuracy

I am currently an intern at a company and working on converting an Access DB to SQL Server 2008 and part of that process including converting one of the VBA Procedures into an SQL Procedure. I can't show all of the code, but can say that the SQL procedure works by running calculations on a string of data sent over by MS Access which is then placed in a temp table (in the original application all calculations are done within Access).

So... 
a string such as '0.33333333333333333, 0.56666667, 0.77778, 0.2355558' would be sent to SQL as string data from Access then this is placed in a temp table with data type Nvarchar(50) calculations are performed on this data exactly as they are in Access and then the data is converted from Float to Nvarchar(50) and inserted into a table at the end.

The following is a set of data that shows the results of the calculations in both the new SQL procedure and the original Access procedure and the discrepancies (a difference between the ones place, or the decimal places)...

Data from SQL...

```
780.5     782.802   16.3333   12.6061
1032.67   1033.89   28.875    20.6451
18.7333   18.3721   6.1275    2.95582
300.296   308.456   26.5384   18.909
565.964   584.555   44.8457   37.7669
822.549   851.571   59.7469   56.0106
```

Data from Access...

```
781.5          782.8022222   15.66666667    12.60611338
1033.166667    1034.100556   26             20.05243342
19.15916667    18.37208333   3.844166667    2.955823309
302.1405833    308.455875    23.13241667    18.9090312
568.2343333    584.55475     42.29116667    37.76690216
824.67775      851.5709583   59.17925       56.01059683
```

Has anyone run into similar issues or might know what the problem is? Is there a different data type that would work better, or perhaps a parameter I should be setting on the float?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20001921/edit) your question: **(1)** Please clarify what you mean by "the SQL procedure works by running calculations on a string of data sent over by MS Access which is then placed in an array". I was under the impression that T-SQL did not support arrays (and a blog post [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/10/27/sql-server-storing-variable-values-in-temporary-array-or-temporary-list/) seems to support that). **(2)** Is the sample data you posted the *source* data, or is it a comparison of the *results* produced by the VBA and SQL procedures?

Comment: @GordThompson I've made the changes as requested, I meant to write temp table instead of query and the sample data are the results of both the new and original applications

Comment: Have you verified that the input values are correct immediately after the SQL procedure converts them to `float` from their string representation (as sent by Access)?

Comment: Yes, when stepping through a couple of data sets in both the new and orig. app I found that all data matched up. I simply can't step through every data set as there are 100's, I just don't get why some aren't calculated properly.

Comment: Are the discrepancies repeatable? In other words, do you have one test case that always fails and always produces the exact same discrepancies?

Comment: Yes, it will consistently return the same wrong results each time it is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that if

- you are reasonably certain that the input values are not getting mangled somehow as they are being converted from `Double` (VBA) to `String` and then to `float` (T-SQL), and
- the discrepancies between the results produced by the VBA procedure and the results produced by the T-SQL procedure are consistent, and
- the VBA procedure is deemed to have been producing the correct results

then there is simply a bug in your T-SQL code. While it is true that `Double` and `float` are both *approximate data types* I think it is **extremely** unlikely that errors introduced by floating-point arithmetic would account for such large discrepancies (e.g., in the third significant digit for the case of `780.5` vs `781.5`).

Both VBA and SQL Server 2008 support interactive debugging so I'm afraid that you're just going to have to run the procedures side-by-side on the same data set and compare intermediate results to try and see where the T-SQL procedure goes off the rails.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the nvarchar(50) column is wide enough?  The sample input you gave is 51 chars long.  If you tried to store that in an nvarchar(50) column, the last character would be truncated.
That might account for the discrepancies you are seeing.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking of each number getting that many characters, not a bunch of numbers strung together.

Comment: nvarchar(50) is wide enough, I did increase the string length which held the string data from Access though and then I used the STR function when converting float to string data at the end of my procedure and now it seems to work much better.